# after new install 12.04 black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: 12.04, boot, screen, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed 12.04 and I got after boot black screen.Next I started in filesafe mode but filesafeX (all options)do not work(black screen.Then I started root shell , remounted rw HD
and on prompt built xorg.conf with:
$>X -configure
I have edited xorg.conf to delete obsolete monitors and screens.
After reboot I get black screen with blinking cursor (no terminals)
what can I do?
how to edit xorg.conf when this could be a problem?## Heading ##

hardware:radeon hd5470 and i3 with i915

Comment: please add the details of your video card to the question